# openldap add acl's for group

Tags: openldap, access-control-list, ldif

It's my first day on ldap
I've read these howto's and posts and could not point it out!

```
https://superuser.com/questions/1122329/ldapadd-gives-syntax-errors-with-openldap
https://serverfault.com/questions/356912/ldap-add-error-80-olcmoduleload-handler-exited-with-1/357018#357018
https://blog.netways.de/2012/01/27/openldap-2-4-x-und-die-acl/
http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html
```

I like to manage a ldap adressbook on this ldap version by dynamic configuration

```
root@vm-ldap:/etc/ldap/schema# /usr/sbin/slapd -VV
@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd  (Ubuntu) (May 11 2016 16:12:05) $
        buildd@lgw01-10:/build/openldap-mF7Kfq/openldap-2.4.42+dfsg/debian/build/servers/slapd
```

I would like to set up acl for a group to manage the contact entrys in the following stucture

[image: Group to manage adressbook]

Could somebody advice me here how to setup the acl by ldapmodify and ldif?

The `{0}config.ldif` looks

```
 {0}config.ldif
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 5851d624
dn: olcDatabase={0}config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: 06453e7c-b46e-1036-893d-e97cab33d7b8
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20170413082206Z
entryCSN: 20170413082206.197889Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20170413082206Z
```

The {1}mdb.ldif is

```
# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 a5a00274
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * non
 e
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=shadowLastChange by self write by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by * read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcDbCheckpoint: 512 30
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcDbIndex: cn,uid eq
olcDbIndex: uidNumber,gidNumber eq
olcDbIndex: member,memberUid eq
olcDbMaxSize: 1073741824
structuralObjectClass: olcMdbConfig
entryUUID: 06460820-b46e-1036-8945-e97cab33d7b8
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20170413082206Z
olcSuffix: dc=ac,dc=test
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=ac,dc=test
olcRootPW:: e1NTSEF9U1BXQXpDcVVPNERCbU15TkhGUXdtS3FVOHNFTUU0OW4=
entryCSN: 20170413092314.034244Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
modifyTimestamp: 20170413092314Z
```

**Update 1**

yesterday I destroyed the database with a wrong config for memberOF

**Update 2**

then I tried

```
add olcAccess:
 {3}to dn.subtree="ou=ab,l=ac,ou=ac-corp,dc=ac,dc=lan"
             by group(s)/groupOfNames/member="cn=ab-edit,ou=groups,dc=ac,dc=lan" manage
```

with

```
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
        additional info: no objectClass attribute
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `ldapadd` / `ldapmodify` a LDIF file with just the attribute.

In the LDIF you have to specify :

- Which entry you want to edit : `dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config`
- Which operation you want to perform : `changetype: modify`
- Which attribute is targeted and how : `add: olcAccess`
- Which is the value : `{3}to dn.subtree="ou=ab,l=ac,ou=ac-corp,dc=ac,dc=lan"
           by group(s)/groupOfNames/member="cn=ab-edit,ou=groups,dc=ac,dc=lan" manage`

So the LDIF you should try to `ldapmodify` must look something like :

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="ou=ab,l=ac,ou=ac-corp,dc=ac,dc=lan"
 by group(s)/groupOfNames/member="cn=ab-edit,ou=groups,dc=ac,dc=lan" manage
```